# Git word diff incorrect

Tags: git

Consider the original source snippet below

```
for linePart in line {
    if let part = format(part: linePart) {
        s.append(part)
    }
}
```

Now some changes have been made to look like this (surrounding context, obviously not whole file)

```
for linePart in line {
    switch linePart {
    case .added: hasAdded = true
    case .removed: hasRemoved = true
    default: break
    }
}

func appendStrings(_ strings: [NSAttributedString]) {
    for v in strings {
        sout.append(v)
    }
}
```

Running a `--word-diff=plain` (or `porcelain`) against this results in the diff below

```
            for linePart in line {
                [-if let part-]{+switch linePart {+}
{+                case .added: hasAdded = true+}
{+                case .removed: hasRemoved+} = [-format(part: linePart)-]{+true+}
{+                default: break+}
{+                }+}
{+            }+}
{+            +}
{+            func appendStrings(_ strings: [NSAttributedString]) {+}
{+                for v in strings+} {
                    [-s.append(part)-]{+sout.append(v)+}
                }
            }
```

I don't understand what goes wrong, but just look at the `[- ... -]` parts. The `[-if let part-]` and `[-format(part: linePart)-]` are now displayed on different lines in the diff. Obviously they should be on the same line.

Why does this happen?

PS: Interestingly if the function `appendString` below is removed or commented out, the diff shows the changes on the correct line

**UPDATE**: If I change the diff algorithm to `--patience` this doesn't happen. If you then switch on `--word-diff-regex=.` it happens again in a less severe form - only half the diff is incorrect.

Comment: What happens if you wrap the if statement in your original code in brackets like this `if (let part = format(part: linePart))`? Diff might not parse that statement correctly.

Comment: Shouldn't `git diff` be more or less source agnostic?

Comment: Well, the only "word" that is unchanged is `=`, which is what diff decided to leave in. It is a bit unexpected but the diff is not incorrect per se.

Comment: It is, if you consider that this implies adding 2 newlines before the `=` according to this diff, which is incorrect.

Comment: I can't see it. the `=` in `if let part = format(part: linePart) {` becomes the `=` in `case .removed: hasRemoved = true`, so it moves down two lines

Comment: Yes I can see how it can work if you apply it this way but the output seems unnecessarily complex and confusing - also bad for figuring out correct line numbers. Would prefer a better (more logical) algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well technically : if you apply the actions listed by the `{+..+}` and `[-..-]` blocks to the starting text, you will reach the end text.

The diff algorithm probably considered that keeping the `" = "` sequence right before the `[-format(part: linePart)-]` would make a shorter editing distance.

Comment: I don't know how to be 100% sure that `word-diff` won't break up lines. The closest I can think of is the `--patience` algorithm you tried, but I don't know its exact specifications.

Comment: `--patience` replaces the basic Myers algorithm diff with one that works on only-unique lines within the current sub-box being diffed (initially this is the whole file pair as an MxN matrix). I did not write a lot about it, but see the end of [chapter 3 here](http://web.torek.net/torek/tmp/book.pdf) (this pdf is incomplete and out of date but the book itself is quite incomplete...).

Comment: Nevermind. Doesn't work. I can't produce a decent viewable line-numbered diff from a word-diff. The format doesn't seem to be suited for it. Problems are even more severe in `porcelain` mode (changes that were on one line spread over multiple lines).